# Insert/Update records along with username and timestamp in VBA using SQL

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have put together some code (below) to update MySQL table using VBA in Excel.
Expected Output- If record does not exist in table, it should be inserted.
If record exists then update along with timestamp when record was updated and excel user who updated it.
Table- test_table
Columns- Geo (varchar), country(varchar), year(varchar), month(varchar), input(Int), time_stamp (Datetime), Updated_by (varchar)
Composite Key- Geo,country,year,month

For the most part, the code works as expected. Except the `time_stamp` and `updated_by` field is updated for all records. My requirement is to update `timestamp` and `updated_by` only when the input field does not match.

------ Code-----------------

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Sub input_data()
    Call sql_connection
    Call add_data
End Sub

Function sql_connection()
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    cnn.Open "DSN=testDB;Database=sandbox;"
End Function

Function add_data()
    Dim rowtable As Integer
    Dim height As Integer
    Dim htstring As String
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim t_geo As String
    Dim t_country As String
    Dim t_year As String
    Dim t_month As String
    Dim t_input As Integer
    
    ' Check till the end of range   
    If Worksheets("input").Range("b3").Value = Null Then
    Else
        height = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
        Worksheets("input").Activate
        For rowtable = 3 To height
            t_geo = Cells(rowtable, 2).Value
            t_country = Cells(rowtable, 3).Value
            t_year = Cells(rowtable, 9).Value
            t_month = Cells(rowtable, 10).Value
            t_input = Cells(rowtable, 11).Value

            ' Insert with On duplicate key to update records if already exists
            strsql = "INSERT INTO test_table" & _
          "(geo, country, year, month, input)" & _
          "VALUES ('" & t_geo & "', '" & t_country & "','" & t_year & "','" & t_month & "'," & t_input & ")" & _
          "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE input = " & t_input & ", time_stamp = DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -7 HOUR), updated_by = '" & t_updated_by & "'"

            rs.Open strsql, cnn
        Next rowtable
    End If

End Function
```

Can someone help with this code? Would like to fix the code so that `updated_by` and `timestamp` are only updated when a new Input value is present.

For example-
Table

```
Geo   Country    Year    Month    Input   Last_updated   Updated_by
NA     US        2022    Jan      20      2022-01-01    abc
NA     US        2022    Feb      30      2022-01-01    abc
NA     US        2022    Mar      40      2022-01-01    abc
NA     US        2022    Apr      50      2022-01-01    abc
```

Now if I try to add another row

```
NA     US        2022    Jan      400
```

**Table should be updated like below**

```
Geo   Country    Year    Month    Input   Last_updated   Updated_by
NA     US        2022    Jan      400     2022-06-29     def
NA     US        2022    Feb      30      2022-01-01     abc
NA     US        2022    Mar      40      2022-01-01     abc
NA     US        2022    Apr      50      2022-01-01     abc
```

With current code the table would update like below which is INCORRECT-

```
Geo   Country    Year    Month    Input   Last_updated   Updated_by
NA     US        2022    Jan      400     2022-06-29     def
NA     US        2022    Feb      30      2022-06-29     def
NA     US        2022    Mar      40      2022-06-29     def
NA     US        2022    Apr      50      2022-06-29     def
```

Comment: What are you using as they Key?

Comment: Key- Geo,country,year,month

Comment: You have created a loop over all records that updates each. No wonder it updates each.

Comment: Don't I need to go over all records to check for Insert/Update? Loop through all records and check if there is duplicate to run  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE